# Summing up two different video feed object amount into one file

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection, video-processing

I have two video feeds and I need to sum up all of the detected cars in both feeds.

Currently I am detecting the objects in one feed and then writing that to file with the date:

```
net = cv2.dnn.readNet('weights','cfg')
classes = []
with open('data/obj.names','r') as f:
    classes = f.read().splitlines()
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('ipaddress')
cap2 = cv2.VideoCapture('ipaddress2')
last_time = 0
while True:
    now = time.time()
    _,img = cap.read()
    height, width, _ = img.shape
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, 1/255,  (416 , 416), (0,0,0) ,swapRB=True,crop=False)
    net.setInput(blob)
    output_layer_names = net.getUnconnectedOutLayersNames()
    layerOutput = net.forward(output_layer_names)
    boxes = []
    car = 0
    confidences = []
    class_ids =[]
    for output in layerOutput:
        for detection in output:
            scores = detection[5:]
            class_id = np.argmax(scores)
            confidence = scores[class_id]
            if confidence > 0.1:
                center_x = int(detection[0]*width)
                center_y = int(detection[1]*height)
                w = int(detection[2]*width)
                h = int(detection[3]*height)
                x = int(center_x - w/2)
                y = int(center_y - h/2)
                boxes.append([x,y,w,h])
                confidences.append((float(confidence)))
                class_ids.append(class_id)
    indexes = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes,confidences,0.5,0.4)
    font = cv2.QT_FONT_NORMAL
    colors = np.random.uniform(0,255,size=(len(boxes),3))
    for i in indexes.flatten():
        labels = str(classes[class_ids[i]])
        if(labels == 'car'):
            car+=1
    if now - last_time >= 1800:
        with open('cars.txt','a') as f:
            f.write(f'{datetime.datetime.now()}: {car}\n')
        last_time = now
    for i in indexes.flatten():
        x,y,w,h = boxes[i]
        label =str(classes[class_ids[i]])
        confidence = str(round(confidences[i],1))
        color = colors[i]
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w , y+h), [0,255,0], 2)
        cv2.putText(img, 'detected cars: '+ + str(car), (20, 20), font, 0.8, (0,0,0),2)
        cv2.imshow('Image',img)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key == 10:
            break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

What would be the easiest way to run two instances of this script and then sum up the values into one txt file?

I've tried just duplicating the necessary lines but that makes the script crash often and is not really a viable option.

Another thing I want to try is subprocesses but I don't really know how to do that.

It could look like:

- Run both scripts from a third script
- extract value directly from the script
- write the value to file along with date

Is this a viable option I should look into? I don't know if you can directly retrieve a value from a script or should it instead write to console and the third script will read from that?

Thanks

Comment: do both feeds show the same place at the same time, just from different perspectives?

Comment: Don't really see how it's relevant but it's over a single lot where one camera looks over one side of the lot and the other looks over the other side of the lot. Same place but different coverages

Comment: it's relevant because had they overlapped, you'd be double-counting objects. ok so you can count objects... what's wrong with adding both sums to get a total?